# Hard Drive Scraping Noise and the Flashing Inquisitive Folder

Tags: hard-drive, folders

Hey I'm having the flashing question mark folder issue.  My hard drive is also making this noise like tschhh, tschhh, tschhh, tschhh.  Holding option does nothing, it just makes it load to a grey screen with no folder.  Does this sound like a hard drive only issue or something more. Could the logic board or some connector be involved?  It is a macbook 2,1

Comment: I just love it how ppl describe noises :) well the flashing question mark indicates it is your drive. The noise it makes it is trying to read.

Comment: try this: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1440

Comment: I dont have the installation disj anymore ;( All the updates are just done from the app store now.

Comment: Actually I just tried the option key thing again and this time a cursor came up, which makes me think its def just the hard drive, I bet if I had a cd in there it'd let me boot from it.  Time for an ssd anyways I suppose.

Comment: Try cmd+r to get in to the repair/recovery mode.